# Heroku Rails app R11 error

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm deploying a Rails 3.2.11 app on Heroku with Thin as my server. When I push to Heroku, it boots Thin just fine, but then it seems to also try to boot WEBrick.

My Procfile is as follows:

> web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT thin -e $RACK_ENV

And my Heroku logs:

```
2013-04-11T14:52:28.276634+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v21 created by XXXXXX@gmail.com
2013-04-11T14:52:28.331285+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 6f63ed4 by XXXXXX@gmail.com
2013-04-11T14:52:28.432372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-11T14:52:28.965697+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-04-11T14:52:30.218480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 9009 thin -e $RACK_ENV`
2013-04-11T14:52:32.898285+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-11T14:52:32.897830+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-04-11T14:52:34.350938+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-11 14:52:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=2010
2013-04-11T14:52:34.350132+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-11 14:52:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-04-11T14:52:34.350707+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-11 14:52:34] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
2013-04-11T14:52:34.350132+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-11 14:52:34] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2013-04-11T14:52:34.407830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-04-11T14:52:34.407675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 2010, should be 9009 (see environment variable PORT)
2013-04-11T14:52:35.572955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-11T14:52:35.560772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Why is it doing this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a plugin I was using, SyntaxHighlighter, had some files in its test directory that started WEBrick. I just removed those, committed, pushed, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Thin instead of WEBrick. You can do this by simply adding this to your gemfile:

```
gem 'thin'
```

Then run `bundle install`, commit the new Gemfile and Gemfile.lock, then push to Heroku.

WEBrick is not meant for production use.

Comment: I'm using Thin and have done all those steps successfully. The problem is that it is booting both

Comment: Update your question with updated error logs now that you're on Thin

Comment: Also, post your Procfile and output from `$ heroku ps -a app_name`

Comment: I was always on Thin. My log file shows where it boots Thin. My Procfile is already there as well.